# native IOS select(UITableview) in jQuery mobile and phoneGap opens automatically

Tags: ios, cordova, jquery-mobile, select

I'm developing phoneGap With jQuery mobile on IOS, one of the pages include JQM native select menue' my problem is that the select is loaded open when the page loads and it cams up with no data, because it init before the page and i get an exception on it when trying to scroll it, the question is can i prevent it from opening, I'm working on this issue for 2 days' does any one know something about it